# Partition rectangle into finite number of squares

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

For what positive real numbers $x,y$ can an $x\times y$ rectangle be partitioned into a finite number of squares?

When $\dfrac{x}{y}$ is a rational number, it is not hard to see that we can partition it.

Also, we can scale the width to $1$, so, say we're dealing with a $1\times c$ rectangle. For what values of $c$ can we do the partition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A rectangle with sides $x$, $y$ and $\frac{x}{y} \not \in \mathbb{Q}$ cannot be partitioned into squares. This is a classical result due to Dehn, Sprague and others.

Indeed, if we have a partition of the rectangle into squares of sizes $l_i$ we get the equality of areas
$$x\cdot y = \sum l_i^2$$
This can be proved by further dissecting the rectangle along the sides of the squares and using the distributive law. The same argument in fact can be used to prove the stronger equality in the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $\mathbb{R}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{R}$:
$$x\otimes y = \sum l_i \otimes l_i$$

Assume now $\frac{x}{y}$ is not rational. Then there exists a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear functional $\phi \colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{Q}$ so that $\phi(x) = 1$ and $\phi(y)= -1$. From the above equality we obtain:
$$\phi(x) \cdot \phi(y) = \sum_i \phi(l_i) \phi(l_i)$$
that is $-1$ is a sum of squares in $\mathbb{Q}$, contradiction.

Note that we do not need to use the existence of a Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, we could as well work with the $\mathbb{Q}$ span of $x$, $y$ and all of the $l_i$'s.

Comment: Why does there exist such a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear functional?

Comment: @Dexter As explained in the last sentence of the answer, consider the ${\mathbb Q}$-span of $x,y$ and all the $l_i$'s. This is a finite dimensional space, so existence of the ${\mathbb Q}$-linear functional on it is easy.

Comment: @Dexter: Because $x$, $y$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, so they are part of a basis. On a basis the values of a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear functional can be chosen arbitrary numbers in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: To write the equality in the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $\mathbb{R}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{R}$, don’t you need the squares to be "rectilinear", i.e. to have sides parallel to the axes ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: Yes, they have sides parallel to the sides of the rectangle, you can assume that; and it's not too difficult to prove.

Comment: @orangeskid "it's not too difficult to prove" : how ? The result is intuitively obvious ("squares whoses sides are in different directions cannot combine well"), but how would you prove it rigorously ? Geometry is full of easy-looking statements that are sometimes hard or even false.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: Assume there are squares whose sides are not parallel to the side of the rectangle and take one on which the height function $(x,y) \mapsto y$ achieves the largest value. Or a similar argument. Of course, consider the plane to be $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: "take one on which the height function $(x,y)\mapsto y$ achieves the largest value" ... and?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: Exactly one vertex of such a square will be on the top side. Let $l_{i_0}$ the smallest of the $l_i$. The top edge of the rectangle has to be covered by some segments of length $l_i$. The segments cannot get closer that $l_{i_0} /\tan \alpha$ to this top point. ($\alpha$ is the angle formed by the slanted side). ...

Comment: @OrestBucicovschi you wrote "Assume now $\frac{x}{y}$ is not rational. Then there exists a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear functional $\phi \colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{Q}$ so that $\phi(x) = 1$ and $\phi(y)= -1$." why is the fact that you assume it is not rational gurantees that linear function that map to 1 and -1?
thank you

Comment: @user2323232 since x and y linearly independent over the rationals, so a part of a basis. now a functional can be defined arbitrarily on elements of a basis. This is linear algebra

Comment: Readers interested in an alternative solution, one which uses Dirichlet's Theorem On Diophantine Approximation rather than Linear Algebra, may go to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3259788/partition-of-a-rectangle-into-squares-problem

Answer (score 0):

Another proof of this fact uses the following (not very complicated) fact from linear algebra:

If a system of linear equations with rational coefficients (that includes the right-hand sides as well) has a solution then it has a rational solution.