# Partition of a rectangle into squares problem

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, approximation, puzzle, combinatorial-geometry

recently I encountered this problem:
"Show that a rectangle can be partitioned into finitely many squares if and only if the ratio of its sides is rational."

I have found the a solution which I need help to understand:

> Clearly, every rectangle with rational ratio of sides can be partitioned into finitely many equal squares. Thus, the interesting part of the problem is the "only if" one.
>   Proof via Dirichlet's simultaneous rational approximation theorem
>   Without loss of generality, we may assume that both sides of our
>   rectange are greater than $1$. We can choose a positive integer $q$
>   such that the product of every coordinate of every vertex of every
>   square in our partition becomes almost an integer after multiplication
>   by $q$. So, we may assume that all these coordinates differ from
>   integers by, at most, $\frac 15$. Now let $a$ and $b$ be the
>   horizontal and the vertical side of our rectangle, respectively, and
>   let $s_i$ be the sides of the squares in the partition. Denote by
>   $\tilde x$ the nearest integer to $x$. Now, draw the horizontal lines
>   at all half-integer heights (i.e., the heights $\pm\frac 1 2,\pm\frac
>  3 2,\dots$) and look at the total length $L$ of these lines within our
>   rectangle. On one hand, we have $L=a\tilde b$. (There are $\tilde b$
>   lines intersecting our rectangle and each of them intersects it by an
>   interval of length $a$.) On the other hand, looking at what happens in
>   each square, we get $L=\sum_i s_i\tilde s_i$. Thus $a\tilde b=\sum_is_i\tilde s_i$. Similarly, drawing the vertical lines through
>   half-integer points, we arrive at the identity  $b\tilde a =\sum_i
>  s_i\tilde s_i$. Thus $a\tilde b=b\tilde a$, i.e., $\frac a b=\frac
>  {\tilde a}{\tilde b}\in\mathbb Q$.

I didn't understood why did he had to use Dirichlet  theorem in order to draw line on each side, particulary I didnt understood why did he had to do this and how everything in this part connected:

> Without loss of generality, we may assume that both sides of our
>   rectange are greater than $1$. We can choose a positive integer $q$
>   such that the product of every coordinate of every vertex of every
>   square in our partition becomes almost an integer after multiplication
>   by $q$. So, we may assume that all these coordinates differ from
>   integers by, at most, $\frac 15$.

If anyone can please explain it, it would be great, thanks

reference for the problem and solution: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Partition_of_a_rectangle_into_squares_problem

I’m asking about the answer he gave, not about any other solution...

Comment: Where did you encounter the problem, please? Where did you find the solution? Where did the author use Dirichlet's Theorem? (It's not in anything you quoted.)

Comment: @GerryMyerson hey, I added a refference to the problem and the solution...

Comment: @GerryMyerson also, its not a duplicate , since this is another side of this problem( he asked if x/y is rattional then ...., and im asking the other side -if it can be partioned then..). also I'm asking about the answer I posted not the answer he added there...

Comment: The question as you quote it is an "if and only if" question. The question may not be a duplicate, but did you read the answer that was posted there?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes I did and I didnt understood it quite well , and I'm asking for help on how they solved it.... just what I wrote at the post..

Comment: The other post does not ask what happens if $x/y$ is rational; it takes for granted that if $x/y$ is rational, then there's a decomposition into squares, and asks what happens if $x/y$ is *not* rational. The answer there proves that if $x/y$ is not rational then there is no decomposition into squares, which is also what the artofproblemsolving answer does. This would have gone a lot better if you had mentioned the earlier post when you put up the question here, indicating where you had difficulty understanding it. (And you still haven't explained how Dirichlet's Theorem is involved.)

Comment: What you can do is edit the question you have posted here, so that it's not the same as the earlier question, and indicate clearly and precisely why it's not the same as the earlier question. Then it may get reopened.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  if you click on their answer you can see that they say that using direchlet they can choose positive integer q such that....   anyway I’m trying to understand if the first part is necessary and if so why?

Comment: By the way, the explanation at http://circuit.ucsd.edu/~yhk/ece269-win18/pdfs/matousek.pdf is similar to the one at the earlier m.se question, but maybe a bit easier to follow, since it doesn't make any use of tensors.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you, but I’m still asking about the particular answer... not about the question itself...

Comment: And I'm still waiting for you to make the edits I suggested. You're still saying the earlier m.se question is about "if $x/y$ is rational..." when it's not, and you're still asking about the Dirichlet theorem without any justification (in the body of the question – hiding it in the comments is not good enough). And, while you're at it, you could try to get the correct spelling of Dirichlet.

Comment: @GerryMyerson added everything... hopefully it’s good enough, also quoted where he talked about Dirichlet theorem...

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted a few days ago?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solver wants to draw horizontal lines through the rectangle, and wants the number of horizontal lines to be $\tilde b$, which is the integer nearest the height of the rectangle. You can do this by drawing the lines at the half-integral heights $\pm1/2,\pm3/2,\pm5/2,\dots$. But things get messy if one or more of those horizontal lines coincides with an edge of a square, as the solver wants to break each horizontal line up into segments, and attribute each segment to exactly one of the squares in the tiling. So, you have to make sure that there are no edges at a half-integral height. That's where Dirichlet's Theorem On Diophantine Approximation comes in; it ensures that given any finite collection of numbers, there is a positive integer $q$ such that you can multiply each of the numbers by $q$ and the resulting numbers won't be half-integers (will in fact differ from the nearest integer by at most one-fifth).

Now the solver is also going to draw vertical lines, and these are also going to be at half-integers (so the number of vertical lines will be $\tilde a$), and these also have to miss the sides of the squares, so the finite collection of numbers to be multiplied by $q$ has to include all the horizontal coordinates, but that's still a finite collection of numbers, so Dirichlet applies.

But why one-fifth, when one-third would be good enough to avoid all the edges of squares? Well, you want the number of line segments in any given square to be $\tilde s_i$, so you want a square to have $s_i$ at least one-half if it has a line segment running through it. With coordinates as much as one-third away from the nearest integer, you could have a square of side one-third with a line segment through it; but with coordinates no more than one-fifth from an integer, a square must have side at least three-fifths to have a segment through it, and $3/5>1/2$.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another (very nice and instructive) proof of this fact (together with the classic electric network approach to the whole theory of squaring of rectangles) is presented in a very good book by Paul Nahin called "Mrs Perkins's Electric Quilt and other Intriguing Stories of Mathematical Physics".